# How to Add an SSH Key to Google Cloud using the CLI

Tags: google-cloud-platform, ssh, gcloud, ssh-keys, gcloud-compute

After generating an RSA-based SSH key:

```sh
ssh-keygen -t rsa -f ~/.ssh/id_rsa -C id_rsa

#=>

Generating public/private rsa key pair.
Created directory '/. . ./.ssh'.
Enter passphrase (empty for no passphrase):
Enter same passphrase again:
Your identification has been saved in /. . ./.ssh/.id_rsa.
Your public key has been saved in /. . ./.ssh/.id_rsa.pub.
The key fingerprint is:
SHA256:. . . id_rsa
The key's randomart image is:
+---[RSA 3072]----+
|      . . .      |
+----[SHA256]-----+
```

I am able to add it to my Google Cloud Platform (GCP) project's (`$GCP_PROJECT_NAME`) Compute metadata:

```sh
gcloud compute project-info add-metadata \
--metadata-from-file ssh-keys=./.ssh/id_rsa.pub

#=>

WARNING: The following key(s) are missing the <username> at the front
ssh-rsa . . . id_rsa

Format ssh keys following https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/adding-removing-ssh-keys
Updated [https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/$GCP_PROJECT_NAME].
```

with a warning, but **unable** to connect to a GCP Compute instance with it.

If I:

```sh
pbcopy < ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
```

and I paste it into the GCP Console, I am able to use it.

How would I accomplish the same thing with the GCP SDK (`gcloud`)?

Comment: Show the last line of your public key. This is where the username part should be present OR just add the public key to your question.

Comment: I do not get it. how can I add username?

Comment: The format of SSH public keys is documented on the Internet. Basically, on the last line add ` myusername`. However, this depends on the format of the key. You might even be using the wrong public key format.

Comment: I am not sure which document you are following to add/remove ssh keys in metadata. The help center article about '[Managing SSH keys in metadata](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/adding-removing-ssh-keys)' seems to be pretty straight forward. Have you checked the '[creating a new SSH key](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/adding-removing-ssh-keys#createsshkeys)' section in that document? To add or remove a project-wide public SSH keys, you can refer [this section](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/adding-removing-ssh-keys#project-wide).

Comment: Thank you for your response. my problem is how to upload ssh key via gcloud cli. I read these two links really carefully.  could you please tell me how to upload ssh key to metadata.

Comment: You need to click on the 'GCLOUD' tab of the '[Adding or removing project-wide public SSH keys](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/adding-removing-ssh-keys#project-wide)'

Answer (score 4):

The:

> WARNING: The following key(s) are missing the  at the front

warning is because the:

```sh
gcloud compute project-info add-metadata
```

command expects SSH keys to be presented as:

```sh
$USERNAME: $(cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub)
```

instead of:

```sh
cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
```

If you want to add your RSA-based SSH key to your Google Cloud Project (GCP) project (`$GCP_PROJECT_NAME`):

1. Make sure you're logged-in as the correct user:

   ```sh
   gcloud config list --format="value(core.account)"
   ```

   if not, log-in using:

   ```sh
   gcloud auth login
   ```
2. Make sure you're connected to `$GCP_PROJECT_NAME` with:

   ```sh
   gcloud config list --format="value(core.project)"
   ```

   if not, switch to `$GCP_PROJECT_NAME` with:

   ```sh
   gcloud config set project $GCP_PROJECT_NAME
   ```
3. Make sure the public and private key files for your RSA-based key still exist:

   ```sh
   ls -1 ~/.ssh/id_rsa*

   #=>

   /. . ./id_rsa
   /. . ./id_rsa.pub
   ```
4. Use the following command to check all project-wide SSH keys for `$GCP_PROJECT_NAME`:

   ```sh
   gcloud compute project-info describe --format=json

   #=>

   {
     "commonInstanceMetadata": {
       . . .
       "items": [
         . . .
         {
           "key": "ssh-keys",
           "value": ". . ."
         },
         . . .
       ],
       . . .  
     }
     . . .
   }
   ```

   Making use of the `filter()` and `firstof()` [transforms](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/topic/projections#Transforms) available for `gcloud`, we are able to grab just those project-wide SSH keys:

   ```sh
   gcloud compute project-info describe \
   --format="value(commonInstanceMetadata.items.filter(key:ssh-keys).firstof(value))"
   ```
5. If we want to avoid generating a temporary file and only use a **single** command to add your RSA-based SSH key to `$GCP_PROJECT_NAME`:

   ```sh
   gcloud compute project-info add-metadata \
   --metadata ssh-keys="$(gcloud compute project-info describe \
   --format="value(commonInstanceMetadata.items.filter(key:ssh-keys).firstof(value))")
   $(whoami):$(cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub)"

   #=>

   Updated [https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/$GCP_PROJECT_NAME].
   ```
6. You *should* now see that RSA-based SSH key now in `$GCP_PROJECT_NAME`; check with:

   ```sh
   gcloud compute project-info describe \
   --format="value(commonInstanceMetadata.items.filter(key:ssh-keys).firstof(value))"
   ```

**Note**: I would suggest using an Ed25519-based SSH key *instead* of an RSA-based SSH key:

```sh
ssh-keygen -t ed25519 -C "$(whoami)@$(hostname)"

#=>

Generating public/private ed25519 key pair.
Enter file in which to save the key (/. . ./.ssh/id_ed25519):
Enter passphrase (empty for no passphrase):
Enter same passphrase again:
Your identification has been saved in id_ed25519.
Your public key has been saved in id_ed25519.pub.
The key fingerprint is:
SHA256:. . . "$(whoami)@$(hostname)"
The key's randomart image is:
+--[ED25519 256]--+
|      . . .      |
+----[SHA256]-----+
```

Answer (score 2):

To add ssh keys to metatdata and expanding @guillaume to show a specific working example with all the fiddly bits included

1 get the existing instance metatdata

```
gcloud compute instances describe <instance name>
```

2 Copy the public SSH keys under the ssh-keys metadata value

3 create a file and include the keys from step 2

4`add the keys to the instance

```
gcloud compute instances add-metadata cos-test --metadata-from-file ssh-keys=<file from step 2>
```

the file  from step 2 should look like this

```
<user name>:ssh-rsa <long string of key data> <user name>
```

on a linux distribution with open-ssh we would create the key with

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa -f ~/.ssh/<key name> -C <user name>
```

confused as to why gcloud wants the username pre/appended, follows from gcloud will create a remote user and home directory based on the appended username with the key. You need to remember this when you login like

```
 ssh -v -i <path to your private key> <username>@<public ip>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can add and remove SSH key with gcloud command. However, if you want to add a ssh key to the existing one, a script is needed.

As described in [the documentation](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/adding-removing-ssh-keys), if there is existing keys on your VM metadata, you have to recover them, add the new one and set the whole package as VM metadata.